# Rotating the age and salary attributes of data set clockwise to $α = 13.7^\circ$.

Tags: statistics, matrix-equations, data-analysis

I am trying to resolve the following data transformation.
Original data has been transformed using random rotation technique as below.
[image]

Rotating the age and salary attributes of data set clockwise to $α = 13.7^\circ$.

Any idea of how the data has been transformed?

Comment: 1. What a sad statement on the lot of teachers everywhere. 2. The transformation is $y' = y\cos\alpha-s\sin\alpha, s' = s\cos\alpha+y\sin\alpha$, where $y$ and $s$ are the original age and salary (in $100$s) and $y'$ and $s'$ are the new values. 3. Why on earth would anyone massage the data this way to get a new data set with these interpretations? We have two people with negative ages!

Comment: *Please* tell me that this is for a school assignment, and you're *not* a corporate payroll department database administrator who accidentally ran a data-perturbing SQL script on the wrong table.

Comment: "We'll decrease your salary by $5k, but you'll get three years younger. Whattaya say?"